# Where do you initialize your object?

Tags: java, android, oop

I'm trying to create a calculator app that stores the frequency of times a button was pressed and then performs various tasks with that info. I thought it would be best to create a separate java file with all the objects and their info to refer to. I am having some issues calling the objects I previously set in the main activity. I know that I have to initialise the object but I don't know where to do it and if I can, in fact, create multiple objects within one class.

public class PriceObjects {

```
public class valuesA {
    public int freqDayA = 0;
    public int freqWeekA = 0;
    public int totalDayA = freqDayA*2;
    public int totalWeekA = freqWeekA*2;
}

public class valuesB {
    int freqDayB = 0;
    int freqWeekB = 0;
    int totalDayB = freqDayB*3;
    int totalWeekB = freqWeekB*3;
}
public class valuesC {
    int freqDayC = 0;
    int freqWeekC = 0;
    int totalDayC = freqDayC*4;
    int totalWeekC = freqWeekC*4;
}
public class valuesD {
    int freqDayD = 0;
    int freqWeekD = 0;
    int totalDayD = freqDayD*5;
    int totalWeekD = freqWeekD*5;
}
public class valuesCustom {
    int freqDayCustom = 0;
    int freqWeekCustom = 0;
    int totalDayCustom = freqDayCustom*40;
    int totalWeekCustom = freqWeekCustom*40;
}
```

}

Is this code any good or should I just keep it all in the MainActivity?
Thanks!

Comment: That's precisely why you have constructors : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: @zakir is right. Write one class Values (classes start with capital letters) and instantiate it for your needs with new, or, maybe better suited for your scenario, with a factory: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm

Comment: By the way, no one needs to downvote you. You're new and trying to learn. Keep asking questions, do your research and you'll get there. ;)

Comment: Your declarations of `totalDayA` etc are useless: setting a field's value to `freqDayA*2` doesn't mean that its value is always double that of `freqDayA`: it simply sets the initial value to double the initial value of `freqDayA`, i.e. `2*0`. If you change `freqDayA`, `totalDayA` will not change too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something to research might be [Model View Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). The idea is that your business logic / objects are models, your actual view is your xml layout file, and your controller that "controls" your view is your activity class. It looks like you may be able to clean up your classes a bit by using some object oriented design. Specifically your values classes. Instead of creating a separate class for each kind of value, why not create something generic that you can reuse like so?

```
public class Values {
    public int freqDay = 0;
    public int freqWeek = 0;

    public int totalDay;
    public int getTotalDay(){
       totalDay = freqDay*2;
       return totalDay;
    }

    public int totalWeek;
    public int getTotalWeek(){
       totalWeek = freqWeek*2;
       return totalWeek;
    }
}
```

That way if you want to be able to store multiple sets of Values you can hold them in a list like so:

```
List<Values> myValues = new ArrayList<Values>();
myValues.add(new Values());
```

These aren't perfect solutions / code, but it's just a little something to get you thinking more about objects / dynamic and reusable code. Hope this gives you somewhere to start looking!

Answer (score 0):

Well here you have created a class inside a class , which is not a best way to write OOPS code . Best is make two classes in one class put all you calculater logic by making in different methods like

```
public class Calculator{

  public void Sum(){
  // Enter the logic
  }

  public void diff(){
  // Enter the login
  }
}
```

now make a main class where you create a object of the calculator class and access different methods like Sum and diff from that object

```
public class mainClass(){
  public static void main(string args[]){
    Calculator obj = new Calculator(); // Object creation
    obj.Sum(); // Accessing the sum method
  }
}
```

In this way you can do it . it is not a full code but this is the approach that all follow in oops